# Which song is very similar to "Vallecito" by John Craigie?

Tags: identify-this-song, rock

I just listened to this very nice ballad by John Craigie: Vallecito, which he published in April 2020. You can listen to it here:

It reminds me very clearly of another song with very similar music (not lyrics) considering the rhythm, the distortion of the guitar, the voice. Can you suggest which song it makes you think of ?

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of several different songs, of which two are the closest matches:

The same chords and rhythm are in the intro and the chorus of Broken Bells "The Ghost Inside" (very different sound and production).

The chords, rhythm and melody are all similar (but not the same) in Martin Sexton's "My Maria", as are the instruments, feel and style. However, that's an obscure track, so perhaps less likely to be the one of which you're thinking.